# Retrieve the subset of fields by querying the embedded field

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-nonrel

Is it possible to retrieve the subset of fields using [Django mongodb nonrel](http://django-mongodb.org/). I am totally new to python, but have good knowledge in mongo.

My requirement is very straight forward, I wanted to query the collection by its embedded field and return only some specific fields

I could do that in mongodb by

```
db.Contract.find({'owner.name':'Ram'},{'address':1})
```

and I tried this in django

```
Contract.objects.filter(owner__name='Ram')
```

but it throws an error

> raise FieldError("Join on field %r not permitted. Did you misspell %r
>   for the lookup type?"  % (name, names[pos + 1])) FieldError: Join on
>   field 'owner' not permitted. Did you misspell 'name' for the
>   lookup type?

am totally struck here. I believe i have my models as specified in the documentation.

```
class SimplePerson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user_key = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Contract(models.Model):
    owner = EmbeddedModelField('SimplePerson')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, )
```

This is really weird.  I could't find any reference in the documentation site about how to query the embedded field & retrieve the subset of fields.

Finally I used [raw_query](http://django-mongodb.org/reference/lowerlevel.html) to query the embedded field

```
Contract.objects.raw_query({'owner.name':'Ram'})
```

But still not able to figure out how to retrieve the subset of fields. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subobject filters aren't possible yet so you need to drop down to `raw_query` (which you already figured out). To retrive a subset of fields, use `.values('field1', 'field2', ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering by EmbeddedField is now possible with the following syntax:

```
Contract.objects.filter(owner={'name': 'Ram'})
```